Serial killer chases teenage actors
I saw this movie 3 or 4 years ago on MTV Colombia. It was about a group of teenage actors who find out there's a serial killer around that's hunting them. The opening scene was a part of their film they were working on, it took place on a plane.
It is definitely a 2000's movie, full color and live action; poorly produced in my opinion, just simple slash horror.

was in in english or another langauge?  were they american or...?

Sounds like Urban Legends: Final Cut. If it is, please let me know and I'll mark this as duplicate.

yes it is, thank you :)

Dupe of Mile High Club & murderer on a plane.
